# What is an efficient way to combine hundreds of data files into a single master DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

As in the title, I have more than 800 data files (all in .csv) (each with size ~ 0-5MB, and each file contains 10 columns with 1st row being the header) and I want to combine all of them into a single DataFrame. I can append them one by one using Pandas data frame but it is very time consuming.

Is there a way to do this faster?

My code:

```
fname = "CRANlogs/" + ffiles[0]
df = pandas.read_csv(fname,header=0)

for i in range(807)[1:]:
    print(i)
    fname = "CRANlogs/" + ffiles[i]
    temp = pandas.read_csv(fname,header=0)
    df = pandas.merge(df,temp,how="outer")
```

Comment: Have you considered appending each loaded csv (each loaded into a df) to a list and then calling `pd.concat(df_list).to_csv(.....)`?

Comment: Please post your code so we have an idea what you are doing and so we can know if what we are suggesting is a (potential) improvement.

Comment: "It depends" - what sort of file format are you using?

Comment: @EdChum not yet, I'm trying now!

Comment: isn't simple reading and writing files sufficient?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko It's really slow....

Comment: @HughBothwell all in .csv, with 10 columns (same column names for each file)

Comment: Try adding each df to a list and then outside of the loop calling `pd.concat(df_list).to_csv`

Comment: Do you want them as one DF to actually work with, or are you purely after having them in just one large file?

Comment: and what is the merge supposed to accomplish? Are you just appending new rows? Not all merges can be replaced by `pd.concat`...

Comment: @JonClements In one DF to work with.

Comment: Sometimes list comprehensions are faster: I'd also try `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob-glob-etc])`. Assuming that you want a giant DataFrame, not a giant csv. For the latter, I'd try bash scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a list of frames and then use pandas concat()

```
frames = [] 

for i in range(807):    
    fname = "CRANlogs/" + ffiles[i]
    temp = pandas.read_csv(fname,header=0)
    frames.append(temp)

#and now concat
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the header of each one? If not it may be faster to convert them all to a numpy array and then use numpy.append feature and then convert the file back to  a csv file.